# Category name or number in url?

Tags: seo

Which url would be better from an SEO perspective, or am I stressing over it to much and it doesn't really matter.

1. www.site.com/forum/category-name/question-title
2. www.site.com/forum/category-number/question-title

The only difference the first url has the category-name written in full and the second url uses a category number.

Thanks for any opinions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

definitely category names, since everything you put in your URL is something google can use.

f.ex: site.com/forum/webdevelopment/ is a lot more meaningful than site.com/forum/3/

Google will understand that first URL, making it easier for you to score on "webdevelopment"

Answer (score 3):

Definitely want to use category names!

Answer (score 0):

think about what visitors will search for. Probably not numbers. So I would choose category name.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for Category Names instead of Category Number as it won't be easy to remember or relate.

Answer (score 0):

i will recommend you to use the first one. it is good practice to use category name in place of number for Google as well as use also. It improve your indexing and ranking.